# How to change the background/foreground color of some characters/words?

Tags: colors, characters

I know by `M-x set-background-color` or `M-x set-foreground-color` one can change the background/foreground of the the entire buffer. Of course this color change only persists in the current session.

In the same way how can one change the background/foreground color of some characters/words?

For example if in a buffer I have something like below

[image]

I would like to change the background/foreground color of some characters like below:

[image]

And I would like that this color change to be persistent in the current session unless I delete these colorful character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are asking, IMO.

There are various ways to highlight a particular character (e.g. everywhere in the region or in a buffer).  Library [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowWhiteSpace#HighlightChars) provides one approach.

Likewise, there are various ways to highlight a word (e.g. everywhere in the region or in a buffer).  Library [Highlight](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) provides one approach.  Ordinary font-lock and hi-lock provides another.

Are you also asking about [persistence of such highlighting](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary#PermanentHighlighting) past the current session?  If so, that too is possible.

Comment: I added some explanations.

Comment: I tested `highlight-chars.el`, it highlights all occurrences of a character. Thus this does not provide the feature I have asked, but it is very useful. Thank you for introducing it.

Comment: I have tested your second link http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary. By `M-x hlt-highlight-region` I can highlight a region (this region can be a character, a word, etc). The background color is fixed (green). For background color, this partially answer the question. But for foreground color the question still remains. Also if I would like to use different colors, the question still remains.

Comment: Read the commentary of the library and the doc strings of the things you use. See, for example, command `hlt-choose-default-face`, mentioned in the doc string of command `hlt-highlight-region`. And read about Emacs **faces** in the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html).

Comment: It turns out that the package `highlight` is exactly what I was looking for. I am trying to use it and to be familiar with it. By `hlt-choose-default-face` one can actually use different colors for highlighting (like the second image in my original post).

Comment: It appears that `highlight` also offers to set the foreground color. The doc says ** ... It has the chosen color as background,
  and its foreground color is determined by the value of user option
  `hlt-auto-face-foreground`.  If that option is nil then
  highlighting does not change the existing foreground color.
  Otherwise, the option value is the foreground color used for
  highlighting. ... ** Let me ask a question I set `(setq hlt-auto-face-foreground "red")`, then I did `M-x hlt-highlight-region` on a region but the foreground color didn't changed. Maybe I misunderstood something here?

Comment: Works for me. Did you set `hlt-auto-face-foreground` before you used `hlt-choose-default-face`? If not, do so. Foreground auto-facing goes hand in hand with background auto-facing.

Comment: Thanks you, I now confirm that if one sets `hlt-choose-default-face` after setting `hlt-auto-face-foreground` it perfectly works.
Let me give some some user-points-of-view after using this package.
(1) If it would be possible to give the background color (`hlt-auto-face-foreground`) interactively (like the background color which can be given in `hlt-choose-default-face`) sometimes it would be helpful.

Comment: (2) Using `M-x hlt-highlight-region` with combination of `hlt-choose-default-face` and `hlt-auto-face-foreground` one can change both foreground and background color.  If one answers `hlt-choose-default-face` by just `RET` the last used color is used. I think if it would be an option in the list provided by `hlt-choose-default-face` to not alter the background color it would be nice
(I mean to not not alter the current background color provided by Emacs, i.e. to do nothing with respect to the background color).

I apologize for these unsolicited personal points-of-views.

Comment: `hlt-choose-default-face` is primarily for what its name says: choose a ***face***. You can alternatively choose just a color - **one** color. The color applies to the **background**. The foreground is then controlled by option `hlt-auto-face-foreground` - by default it is not highlighted.  If you want to highlight only the foreground, either choose a **face** or choose the *frame* background color (for the highlight background) and customize `hlt-auto-face-foreground` to a color for the highlight foreground. I recommend that you choose a **face**, if you want to highlight the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

This demonstration defines a highlighting color and commands which use anonymous faces to highlight a character or word.

```
(defvar my-hl-color "#ff00ff")

(defun my-hl-thing (boundaries)
  (put-text-property (car boundaries) (cdr boundaries)
                     'font-lock-face `(:background ,my-hl-color)))

(defun my-hl-character ()
  (interactive)
  (my-hl-thing (cons (point) (1+ (point)))))

(defun my-hl-word ()
  (interactive)
  (my-hl-thing (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))
```

Comment: Thank you. `my-hl-character` seems to work, but  let me report that when the character is in a comment area it seems to not working. Let me also report that  when a word is the last word of buffer it seems that `my-hl-word` seems to not properly work.